# Compare year month in data frame and retrieve current month -1

Tags: r, date

In a data frame with 2 date columns, how can I compare the month year and create a new variable? In particular I would like to compare dat1 with sysdat and check if dat1 is in the month prior to the month of sysdat.

```
df <- data.frame(dat1 = as.Date(c("2019-01-01","2019-02-15","2019-08-23","2019-09-12")),
             sysdat = as.Date(c("2019-09-24","2019-09-24","2019-09-24","2019-09-24"))
```

The result I would like is an extra column displaying 1 if dat1 is one month prior to the month of sysdat and 0 in all other cases. So in the example below that would only be row 3.

```
dat1     sysdat x
1 2019-01-01 2019-09-24 0
2 2019-02-15 2019-09-24 0
3 2019-08-23 2019-09-24 1
4 2019-09-12 2019-09-24 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R, we can extract year and month from the columns using `format` and return 1 if the years are same and the difference between months is 1.

```
df$x <- with(df, as.integer(format(dat1, "%Y") == format(sysdat, "%Y") & 
      (as.integer(format(sysdat, "%m")) - as.integer(format(dat1, "%m")) == 1)))

df
#        dat1     sysdat x
#1 2019-01-01 2019-09-24 0
#2 2019-02-15 2019-09-24 0
#3 2019-08-23 2019-09-24 1
#4 2019-09-12 2019-09-24 0
```

---

In `lubridate`, we can use `year` and `month` functions to get year and month respectively.

```
library(lubridate)
df$x <- with(df, as.integer(year(dat1) == year(sysdat) & 
                (month(sysdat) - month(dat1) == 1))
```